# Почему не получается сделать элемент невидимым при прокрутке страницы до конца?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Уже много чего смотрел, никак не могу понять, в чем ошибка. У меня меню, которое прилипает к экрану и исчезает при появлении футера. Пока пытаюсь сделать чтобы оно исчезало просто при прокрутке вниз до конца.

```
var hght = 95;   
var mrg = 0; 
$(function(){

  var elem = $('#menu');
  var top = $(this).scrollTop();

$(window).scroll(function(){
      top = $(this).scrollTop();
     if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
      elem.hide();
      }
    if (top+mrg < hght) {
      elem.css('top', (hght-top));
    } else {
      elem.css('top', mrg);
    }
  });
});
```

Погуглил как определить прокрутку до конца

```
if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
  elem.hide();
}
```

Но элемент исчезает только если прокрутить вниз, потом снова наверх. Работало также если писал

```
if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(window).height()/3){
  elem.hide();
}
```

Но это же не правильно, потому что тогда код привязан к размеру скролла и контента. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно сделать. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: можете добавить минимальный рабочий пример?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
var scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
var footerPosition = $('.footer').position().top //- $('.footer').height()
if(scrollBottom >= footerPosition) elem.hide();
```

В моём случае для позиционирования футера использовался отрицательный margin, поэтому требовалась ещё часть после комментария.